# collectd: using dynamic IP for network plugin

Tags: domain-name-system, dynamic-ip, collectd

I've setting up a server which collects statistics of different other servers. I'm using the network plugin of collectd, so I configured the plugin network by setting up a listener.

In my network, I can use the private IP for "Server" in the configuration. Everything works. One of these servers is a remote server and can only be reached through the internet. So the server is configured to send the data to an DNS-address (see config snippet). After starting the service of collectd on this server it works perfect. If I get a new dynamic IP-address for my connection, the remote server doesn't send data to collectd. Only if I restart collectd on the remote server, it works until the IP-address will be changed again.

In my opinion the plugin resolves the DNS-address only once at startup. Is there any option to solve my problem without restarting the collectd service?

config:

```
<Plugin network>
#       # client setup:
        Server "name.of.server" "25826"
</Plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any option to solve my problem without restarting the collectd service?

This question had been asked [also seven years ago](http://mailman.verplant.org/pipermail/collectd/2007-October/001267.html). But still no workaround for this limitation except restarting collectd.

See also similiar github issue: [Network plugin not automatically reconnecting with dynamic IP address](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/issues/406)

> The network plugin is using UDP, so there's no real "connection" taking place. Fixing this would mean doing a DNS lookup for each batch of values sent over the network, which would be a compromise over performance.
>
> I guess this is a problem you're also seeing with other "client-server" systems sharing this setup ? Aren't you able to notify collectd of the server IP address change ? Or cron a reload of collectd at the time the DHCP lease expires ? Or use the AMQP plugin to ship the values to the server without risking any loss ? I'm sure we can imagine other solutions for what really looks more like a network setup problem.